# react-native-map crashing the application

Tags: google-maps, react-native, react-native-maps

I tried to use react native app and having the following snippet in gradle file

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-maps')
    implementation project(':react-native-geolocation-service')
    implementation project(':react-native-background-timer')
    implementation project(':react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation')
    implementation project(':react-native-contacts')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}
```

I have googled and found below lines solving the issues

```
compile(project(':react-native-maps')) {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+'
```

But i dont have compile(project.... in my gradle file

I am using

```
 "react": "16.6.3",
 "react-native": "0.58.6",
 "react-native-geolocation-service": "^2.0.0",
 "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.1.0",
 "react-native-maps": "^0.23.0",
```

How to resolve this issue

Comment: `implementation` replaces `compile`. So you can just switch it. So where you see `compile`, use `implementation` instead.

Comment: I didn't get that

Comment: Ok Ok I got let me check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`compile` was deprecated in favour of `implementation`. You can easily just replace all instances of the word `compile` with the word `implemenation`. So your dependencies would become something like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation(project(':react-native-maps')) {
      exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
      exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+'


    // implementation project(':react-native-maps') // <- you can remove this as you are using it above
    implementation project(':react-native-geolocation-service')
    implementation project(':react-native-background-timer')
    implementation project(':react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation')
    implementation project(':react-native-contacts')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}
```

Comment: Yes I got that but now I am getting error Android dependency 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location' has different version for the compile (11.8.0) and runtime (11.4.2) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

Comment: That's probably because you are using `+`  should use a specific version for play-services-location. Using `+` is never a good idea as it just installs the latest and can cause build issues

Answer (score 3):

I spent forever on this, finally stumbled on two things. This goes in your `build.gradle` for your project (not the `app/build.gradle` one):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
                def requested = details.requested
                if (requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms') {
                    details.useVersion '12.0.1'
                }
                if (requested.group == 'com.google.firebase') {
                    details.useVersion '12.0.1'
                }
            }
        }
        // ... whatever else you have here already
    }
}
```

Just go with your standard react-native settings in your `app/build.gradle`, don't try and exclude groups in here - this didn't work for me.

This made Android <9.0 work - great. However 9.0+ crashed, not cool. I randomly stumbled upon this information :

```
If you are using com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0 
or below and your app is targeting API level 28 (Android 9.0) or 
above, you must include the following declaration within the 
<application> element of AndroidManifest.xml.

<uses-library
    android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
    android:required="false" 
/>
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/config#specify_the_google_play_services_version_number

I really hope this library gets upgraded soon. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for the answer from @hsearle
In our case we are using react-native-maps and I'm assuming that they somehow link (guess who is not a bonifide react-native expert) ;)

anyways we updated to SDK 28 and the maps started crashing the app.

Below code within the application element of AndroidManifest.xml for the win!!

```
    <uses-library
        android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
        android:required="false" 
    />
```

Comment: In my case, I solved the problem only with this code.

Answer (score 0):

you have open wrong file . go in the Project/android/app/build.gradle 
open build file and paste the dependencies

Comment: Nope I am in the current file I have all my dependencies in this file and android/build.gradle says " dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }"

Comment: open this Project/android/app/build.gradle . you have open Project/android/build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the underlying maps library. Please also see this documentation from Google:-https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/config#specify_requirement_for_apache_http_legacy_library

The solution is :- Put this line of code in the Manifest file under the `<application>` tag:

```
`<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>`
```

Answer (score 0):

For expo:

```json
"android": {
   "package": "com.codingmechanic.mapcuny",
   "config": {
      "googleMaps": { "apiKey": "<Your API Key>" }   
   }
}
```

[Create a React Native App with Google Map using Expo.io](https://medium.com/nycdev/create-a-react-native-app-with-google-map-using-expo-io-68041252023d)